# Reading Manifest.mf in war file using java

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I am trying to read `MANIFEST.MF` inside a `war` file. I am using `Eclipse`.

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
    "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

I have this code but I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I have my `war` file inside my project folder.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A WAR is basically an archive of files, so if the manifest be contained in the WAR you will have to open the latter first, or use an API which can do this for you.

Comment: Are you sure the file is there? Try without the leading slash `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");` or with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");`

Comment: The .war file’s manifest may not be available via Class[Loader].getResource[asStream] at all, since ClassLoaders of servlet containers do not look in the root of a .war file;  they look at WEB-INF/classes and each .jar in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen any APIs you can suggest? I've read a lot of sites and most of them suggests `InputStream` but I am open for suggestions. Thank you!

@Tunaki thanks for reply. I have tried both but no luck. still got null.

@VGR oh! thanks for the info. noted.

Comment: are you sure that your war file has been added to your classpath? this can only work if the war is part of the classpath

Comment: @NicolasFilotto hey man, thank you! what i am doing is dragging my war file to src folder where my java class is. tried to add in on my classpath and worked like a charm. thank you so much! thanks everyone! i can't believe i am doing this for 2 days already. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `war` file is part of your `classpath` otherwise what you try to do won't work.

Comment: Thanks man! I was looking for the button where i can mark your answer as best response.